# Dual boot windows ubuntu internet cannot connect to server

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, drivers, wireless, internet

I installed windows 10 trial version after Ubuntu 16.04, and my wifi and ethernet for Ubuntu stopped working. My Ubuntu used to have some wifi connection issues ( slow speed or cannot connect, which happens to all ubuntu systems, so that is another problem.), but usually ethernet works. The ethernet or wifi for windows 10 works fine. I suspect there is a driver conflict but I don't know what to do.

This answer[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/622151/848642) suggest a solution for ethernet, but I couldn't find similar solution for wifi connections.

Ubuntu is also known for not being well-supported by most wifi chipset manufacturers, so I tried three wifi adapters rtl8192cu, TL-WN722N_V3(rtl8188eu), and TP-Link TL-WR710N (Atheros AR9331). Network Manager shows all of them can detect wifi signals from different routers, but they fail to connect to internet when I use browsers or ping command.

I can connect to the router 192.168.1.1.

I can't connect to https://tplinklogin.net, or 192.168.1.254, which is the admin page for setting the wifi adaptor TL-WR710N.

I can't connect to internet via either usb tethering or wifi hotspot to my phone data plan.

```
 lshw -C network
 WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
   *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 00
   serial: 30:9c:23:3c:a9:be
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=192.168.1.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:130 memory:df200000-df21ffff

   *-network:0
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:7
   logical name: wlxe84e0624c146
   serial: e8:4e:06:24:c1:46
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated

   *-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:14
   logical name: wlx503eaa705446
   serial: 50:3e:aa:70:54:46
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188eu ip=192.168.1.6 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
 WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

 iwconfig

 wlxe84e0624c146  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

 enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlx503eaa705446  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"CASAYES-2G"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 18:9C:27:E6:B1:8F   
      Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=91/100  Signal level=67/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

 ifconfig

 enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:9c:23:3c:a9:be  
      inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::8b5f:698f:176f:b36c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:427 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:37526 (37.5 KB)  TX bytes:38005 (38.0 KB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:df200000-df220000 

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:12964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:12964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1170822 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1170822 (1.1 MB)

 wlx503eaa705446 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:3e:aa:70:54:46  
      inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b67f:6542:b17c:707c/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2605:e000:150f:c6a8:11dc:e022:1911:ccef/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2605:e000:150f:c6a8::1/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2605:e000:150f:c6a8:83f2:e92e:d885:6fd3/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4029 (4.0 KB)  TX bytes:18154 (18.1 KB)

 wlxe84e0624c146 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:4e:06:24:c1:46  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update your kernel version or try to find a compatible one.

Generally, running an upgrade on your current distro should install a newer kernel and ideally fix your issues

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

If you're still having driver issues after that, then you'd have to manually do a kernel downgrade to fix your problem.

Try this guide for that:

https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Or if you wanna hit it terminal style, use this guide to get a stable kernel version and update likewise

[What is the lastest stable kernel and how to install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777627/what-is-the-lastest-stable-kernel-and-how-to-install-it)

EDIT: 
As from your comment, you can try to force the configuration by using dhclient
For example, using the wlx503eaa705446 adapter

```
sudo dhclient wlx503eaa705446
```

That should force a network configuration for proper DNS resolution.

Comment: I don't have internet connection, so I can't use apt upgrade. Besides, my kernel is the 4.15, which very new. I will try downgrade it to 4.10 or 4.4.

Comment: I believed from the previous question that you had been able to fix the internet issues for LAN.